# Random from Array

Tags: java, arrays, random

I have a txt file I put into an array. The data in the txt file has data in the format as:

```
Order #     Date     Name     City     State    Zip Code
```

across a row with each item representing a column.

Then there is a 1000 more rows that have these filled in with answers. I want to randomly pick out 5 of these rows. For some reason, it only prints out the first line (Order #, Date, etc).

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rewards {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    String fileName = ("C:/Users/Jordan/Desktop/Project5Text.txt");
    FileReader fin = new FileReader(fileName);
    Scanner src = new Scanner(fin);
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    src.useDelimiter(":");

    while (src.hasNext()) {
        lines.add(src.nextLine());
        System.out.println(src.next());
    }
    System.out.println(lines);
    String[] lineArray = new String[lines.size()];
    lines.toArray(lineArray);

    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            String random = (lineArray[new Random().nextInt(lineArray.length)]);
            System.out.println("Random Winner is " +random);
        }

    }

}
}
```

Here is some of the text file which I am using.

```
Order # Date First name Middle Initial Last name Address City State Zip Email Transaction Amount

1 8/26/2012 Kristina H Chung 947 Martin Ave. Muncie CA 46489 khchung@business.com $593

2 11/16/2012 Paige H Chen 15 MainWay Rd. Dallas HI 47281 phchen@business.com $516

3 11/10/2012 Sherri E Melton 808 Washington Way Brazil CA 47880 semelton@business.com $80

4 9/20/2012 Gretchen I Hill 56 Washington Dr. Atlanta FL 47215 gihill@business.com $989

5 3/11/2012 Karen U Puckett 652 Maplewood Ct. Brazil FL 46627 kupuckett@business.com $826

6 7/4/2012 Patrick O Song 679 MainWay Rd. Lafayette GA 47161 posong@business.com $652
```

---

Here is some of the text file which I am using.

Order # Date    First name  Middle Initial  Last name   Address City    State   Zip Email   Transaction Amount

1   8/26/2012   Kristina    H   Chung   947 Martin Ave. Muncie  CA  46489   khchung@business.com    $593

2   11/16/2012  Paige   H   Chen    15 MainWay Rd.  Dallas  HI  47281   phchen@business.com $516

3   11/10/2012  Sherri  E   Melton  808 Washington Way  Brazil  CA  47880   semelton@business.com   $80

4   9/20/2012   Gretchen    I   Hill    56 Washington Dr.   Atlanta FL  47215   gihill@business.com $989

5   3/11/2012   Karen   U   Puckett 652 Maplewood Ct.   Brazil  FL  46627   kupuckett@business.com  $826

6   7/4/2012    Patrick O   Song    679 MainWay Rd. Lafayette   GA  47161   posong@business.com $652

Comment: Are you sure you are reading more than one line?  I would step through your code in a debugger to see what it is really doing.

Comment: Why don't you use the `ArrayList` directly? Using an array serves no purpose.

Comment: Try to Split the line and display as per your requirements

Comment: Can you give us a little `file` example so we can test it?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

**(1) The scanning loop is wrong**

In every iteration, you're calling `src.next()` for debug output. But this will read to the next occurence of ':', which is not contained in your file, so the complete file is read. There is nothing left for the next iteration.

Solution: Remove the additional call to `src.next()`:

```
while (src.hasNextLine()) {
    lines.add(src.nextLine());
}
```

Possibly you'll have to do some tests inside the loop to exclude empty lines etc.

Hint: Debugging your code usually helps to find problems like this!

**(2) You're not reusing the `Random` generator**

You are creating a new `Random` generator in every iteration of your loop instead creating one before the loop and reusing it. The default constructor of `Random` uses the current system time (`System.currentTimeMillis()`) as seed, so if you create several instances at (almost) the same time, they all will produce the same sequence of 'not-so-random-any-more' numbers. (Note that on some systems, `System.currentTimeMillis()` does not have real millisecond resolution).

Solution: Create one instance of `Random` and reuse it:

```
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    String winner = (lineArray[random.nextInt(lineArray.length)]);
    System.out.println("Random Winner is " + winner);
}
```

Note that this will not necessarily mean that you won't get two lines twice - it's like if you always put back the ball into the bucket in the lottery. Instead, you should remove the line from the list to make sure it does not influence the result of the next iteration.

**(3) The header line is included in your results**

Usually, you don't want to have the header line rewarded, so either remove it from the list, or make sure, it cannot be selected:

```
String winner = (lineArray[1 + random.nextInt(lineArray.length - 1)]);
```

Comment: I have changed it to just try to find one random element, but it still only returns Order #, Date, etc.

Comment: You're right, there is another bug in your code. I'll modify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    String fileName = ("test.txt");
    FileReader fin = new FileReader(fileName);
    Scanner src = new Scanner(fin);
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    src.useDelimiter(":");
            int nChoices = 3;

    Random rand = new Random();

    while (src.hasNext()) {
        String l = src.nextLine();
        if (!l.equals("")) // So we don't add blank lines
            lines.add(l);
    }
    // System.out.println(lines.size());
    String[] randomChoices = new String[nChoices]; // Number of random choices

    for (int i = 0; i < randomChoices.length; i++) {
                    // Here makes the random choice, starting from line 1
        String randomString = lines.get(1 + rand.nextInt(lines.size() - 1));
        randomChoices[i] = randomString;
    }

    for (String s : randomChoices)
        System.out.println(s);

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this out and it prints out the randoms that I need. I do have one problem though. I would like the arraylist to print out as well. But when I try, it only prints out in one long line, instead of in separate columns.

Comment: It doesn't work with: `for (String s : arraylist)` ?? What is the output?